# Seaborn lmplot multiple regression issue

Tags: python, pandas, regression, seaborn, lmfit

I am just using the minimum working example from Seaborn's `lmplot` and I can't seem to get multiple regressions to display correctly.  I am able to get a single data set to display the linear regression, but when I have two groups I can't get the line to display?  Here is the code for reference.  I have also included a figure to show what it looks like.

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips,
               palette="Set1")
```

[image: Linear regression]

Comment: very curious. I cannot reproduce the problem. Please make sure you have restarted your kernel and updated all packages to the latest version.

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea why this is happening.  I just did an update to `seaborn` and `pandas` which I used to generate the plots.  It still looks like it is doing the same thing.  When I run the command via `spyder` I am getting the following error message:  `c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:1965: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  large = s > cutoff`